# How to interact with back-end script via a button

Tags: html, node.js

I have a very simple node.js setup:

demo1.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="hello">My Button</button>
    <p>My paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

myfirst.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', async function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });

}).listen(8080);
```

In basic html, I can either call the function by putting `onclick=""` or `.addEventListener`.
However, the function that I wanted to call contains secrets and of course, I don't want the client see it via source code/inspect.

May I know how can a button interact with the backend script WITHOUT `onclick` and accessible script files. The script should ONLY be in the backend script, i.e. `myfirst.js`?

Edit: I tried putting `.addEventListener` in `myfirst.js` and there is a reference error: `document is not defined`

Comment: You want to make use of AJAX to call a back-end that contains the secret, which would return it as a response. This would also allow you to add layers of auth.

Comment: You'll need a frontend script which on button click sends a AJAX request to the backend.